# Deploying a pre-built package to Appharbor

Tags: appharbor

I couldn't find any information on Appharbor's website about the possibility to deploy pre-built asp.net (mvc) applications. Does anyone know if that's doable?

Another question I have is wether appharbor's built process supports project that launch an executable (node.exe in this case) that's included in a solution folder as part of a custom build step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about precompilation, that's something [AppHarbor does out of the box](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/05/07/build-improvements). If you push a repository without a solution file, we won't build it, but just [deploy the contents](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/build-process-and-solution-file-convention) (see part with no solution file).

You should also be able to run node.exe as part of the build, as long as all dependencies (incl. `node.exe`) are in the repository.

Comment: Thanks. Will appharbor still apply appConfig substitution in the case where in absence of a solution file the contents are used verbatim?

Comment: They will indeed, in fact replacements are generally not done by the build, but by the deployengine, just as the build is deployed.